# Prove that this is an Equivalence Relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

Then give information about the equivalence classes as specified for

> The relation $R$ on $ℝ$ given by $xRy$ iff $x-y∈ℚ$. Give the equivalence class of $0$; of $1$ ; $\sqrt{2}$.

First In order to solve this problem one must list  what he/she knows in order to solve this problem.

**Reflexive** : R is reflexive on $A$ iff for all $x∈ A$, $xRx.$

**Symmetric** : R is symmetric iff for all $x$ and $y∈ A$ if $xRy,$ then $yRx.$

**Transitive**: R is transitive on A if for all $x$,$y$ $z ∈A$ if $xRy$, and $yRz$ then $xRz$.

An **equivalence relation**  is defined if something is reflexive,symmetric, and transitive on A.

My question is how does one determine how this is a Reflexive relationship ?Does one have to substitute real numbers or rational numbers into the equation in order to find the relation. Does this also apply to Symmetric and transitive?

I also know how to determine an equivalence class, $\frac{x}{R} =$ {$ y∈A: xRy$}. I am just perplexed on how one proceeds.

This is what I have deduced so far.

$[0]$ = { $x ∈   ℝ$ : $0$Rx}

Any *advice* on how to proceed and  *solve*

this, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation is reflexive since for all $x \in \Bbb R$, we have $x-x = 0 \in \Bbb Q$. To write the classes, use the definition of the relation. For the other properties, you have to check that if $x,y,z \in \Bbb R$ are such that $x-y,y-z\in \Bbb Q$, then $x-z \in \Bbb Q$, and finally that if $x-y \in \Bbb Q$, then $y-x \in \Bbb Q$.

About the classes, for instance, we have $$[0] = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid xR0\} = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x - 0 \in \Bbb Q\} = \Bbb Q.$$In general, the classes will be "copies" of $\Bbb Q$ shifted by the representant, as in $$[\sqrt{2}] = \sqrt{2}+\Bbb Q = \{ \sqrt{2}+q \mid q \in \Bbb Q  \},$$ etc.

Comment: So for this problem does one not need  to show a scenario where it is transitive and symmetric? So since x is real numbers y is rational numbers is that why it is symmetric?

Comment: Why shouldn't you have to prove the other properties? Of course you have to. I said it in the answer, to prove symmetry you take $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Then assume that $x-y \in \Bbb Q$. And check that $y-x \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: You misunderstand, I just wanted to know that what you said above is enough to justify whether it be symmetric and transitive now I know more work is required. Sorry for the discrepancies.

Comment: Yes, it is the *definition* of these properties. What does $xRy$ mean? Look at the definition of the relation we're given.

Comment: X is a relationship to y.

Comment: Everywhere after you used $R$. Meaning, we're given the definition of $S$ and asked to give classes of $R$, makes no sense. You can rollback the edit if it bothered you, it was a minor thing.

Comment: Nah no worries this way it will make more sense in the future.